# Calling a method in Python file from the Keyword section of a Robot file

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to call a Python function residing in a separate .py file from the Keyword section of a .robot file.

Is there any way to do that? Right now the function name residing in the .py file is not recognised from the .robot file.

```
a.py

Class abc:
   def func:
       ...


x.robot
Library a.py

*** Keywords ***
Calling abc
    func

Is there any way that func is accessible from the .robot file?
```

Comment: This isn't Python. `Class` should not be capitalized, your `func` doesn't take arguments (not even a `self`, or even the parentheses for that matter), and I legitimately have no idea what's happening with the bottom half. If you need help debugging Python code, then we need to see a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Not an approximation, but something *runnable*.

Comment: Apologies for providing the wrong syntax. Will provide the entire reproducible code. But my question here is, whether it is possible to call a python function from the keyword section of the .robot file?All the other examples calls the function from the ***Test Cases*** section

Comment: Yes it is. All python methods in modules that were imported using `Library` are considered as `Keywords`. You are allowed to call any robot `Keyword` from `Keywords` section including ones from custom python libraries.

Answer (score 1):

if you use a class in python code, instead of a plain module, your *classname* should be the same as the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to call the python function to the robot file.

For example, consider this as your python file as test.py

```
def add(number1, number2):
   sum = number1 + number2
   return sum
```

Now you can import that test.py python file into your robot file.

```
*** Settings ***
Library   test.py

*** Variables ***
${num1}    10
${num1}    20

*** Keywords ***
FunctionCall
    ${output}     add     ${num1}    ${num2}
    Log    ${output}
```

Note: Make sure to keep robot file and python file in the same folder or give the path of python file while importing.